# Bluetooth LE send string data between Android devices via application

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm completely clueless on how to use BLE. I need to create an application for Android devices that sends a small string from one Android device to the other. I am NOT using any sensor type devices. I only need to send a string from one phone to another phone using a BLE connection. From what I understand, I need to create a custom service and implement a GATT server on a central device and have a peripheral device access it as a client but I'm not even sure if that's what I need for my situation. I have scoured the internet and nothing I have found deals with this topic specifically. I have no idea how to create a GATT server for this purpose and what I need to include in order to create a service. Can someone please explain to me what I need to do or point me towards some resources that are useful for A COMPLETE NOVICE? Thanks.

Comment: When I started work with BLE this videos was helpful for me:
https://youtu.be/zeN88yh7YdY
https://youtu.be/qx55Sa8UZAQ

Comment: Thanks, watching those now and they already seem helpful in explaining the basics.

Answer (score 1):

You are right so far. You need to create two applications on two different Android devices as follows:-

- Android App A on Device #1: An app to act as a **GATT Server** to host your data that you want to send. For that, you will need [GATT Server API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattServer).
- Android App B on Device #2: An app to act as a **GATT Client** to connect to Device #1 and read the string data from the GATT Server using [GATT Client API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt).

BLE is a relatively complex technology but luckily there are so many resources to help you get started. I recommend that you first understand how BLE technology works and for that I the following links are useful:-

- [Introduction to BLE Video Series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eZGixQzBo7Y&list=PLYj4Cw17Aw7ypuXt7mDFWAyy6P661TD48)
- [The Basics of Bluetooth Low Energy](https://www.novelbits.io/basics-bluetooth-low-energy/)
- [Introduction to BLE GATT](https://learn.adafruit.com/introduction-to-bluetooth-low-energy/gatt)
- [Getting Started with Bluetooth Low Energy](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/getting-started-with/9781491900550/ch01.html)
- [Getting Started with BLE GATT](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/getting-started-with/9781491900550/ch04.html)

Once you have a better understanding of the protocol, the following links are useful for understanding Android BLE development (in addition to the video posted in the comment):-

- [The Ultimate Guide to Android Bluetooth Low Energy](https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/?utm_source=BlogEmail&utm_medium=Email&utm_campaign=BlogRoundUp&mc_cid=9113555d36&mc_eid=767bbcdc1b)
- [Getting Started with Bluetooth Low Energy in Android](https://medium.com/omisoft/getting-started-with-bluetooth-low-energy-connection-in-android-24c394188c30)
- [How to use Android BLE to Communicate between Devices (With Examples)](https://medium.com/@shahar_avigezer/bluetooth-low-energy-on-android-22bc7310387a)

However, before going through any of these, it's always a good idea to get a feel and practical understanding of how the technology works. For that I recommend using the [nRF Connect Android](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Development-Tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile) app to connect and read data off devices. This way, you'll be able to relate to the new information and hopefully understand the new concepts easier.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the feedback and helpful resources.