# Standard and custom GATT characteristic

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I'm writing apps for android phone and android watch (wearOS). The apps will communicate with each other via bluetooth. Basically the app on android phone will bond with the WearOS device  and then communicate with the app on WearOS to start specified function, get battery information, ...

I know I should use GATT characteristics for standards information like battery, device name, ...

Please help to advise on these two questions:

Where can I get the full list of standard characteristics UUIDs?

How can I define custom characteristics for custom informations/features like "Show photo" or "Play a sound"?

Many thanks

Comment: _"Where can I get the full list of standard characteristics UUIDs?"_ Maybe here: [https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Where can I get the full list of standard characteristics UUIDs?**

This is the document found at the link that Markus Kauppinen shared:-

https://btprodspecificationrefs.blob.core.windows.net/assigned-values/16-bit%20UUID%20Numbers%20Document.pdf

At around page 12, you'll find the beginning of "**GATT Characteristic and Object Type**". At around page 19, you'll find the beginning of "**GATT Services**".

**How can I define custom characteristics for custom informations/features like "Show photo" or "Play a sound"?**

I recommend the following links which cover how to create a BLE GATT Table on Android:-

- [Android: Using a GATT Server](https://riptutorial.com/android/example/30768/using-a-gatt-server)
- [Sample BLE GATT Server](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-bluetooth-le-gattserver)
- [Nordic's Android BLE Library](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-BLE-Library) (Check GATT Server Support)
- [BluetoothGattServer Android API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattServer)

Additional Resources

- [The Ultimate Guide to Android BLE Development](https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/)
- [How to Design Custom Services and Characteristics](https://www.novelbits.io/bluetooth-gatt-services-characteristics/)
- [BLE Characteristics: A Beginner's Tutorial](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/nordic/short-range-guides/b/bluetooth-low-energy/posts/ble-characteristics-a-beginners-tutorial)
- [BLE: Sending Data between Two Android Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65636725/bluetooth-le-send-string-data-between-android-devices-via-application)

Comment: Your links gave me a lot of understanding how Bluetooth devices connect and work together. Many thanks