# Bluetooth GATT send data to BLE device

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

how can I send Data to BLE device. I already Connected to ble device but don't know how to send and receive data Via Gatt Callback.

Comment: The exact API (functions) depends on OS but common way to send data is to write to the writable characteristic value. There are 2 way to receive data: read from readable characteristic or subscribe to notifications or indications. Detailed description can be found by this link: https://www.btframework.com/ble.htm

Comment: Im using Android. I have managed to connect the two device. All I need now is to read and write data on BLE.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with Android development but fast Google search gives this link: https://github.com/android/connectivity-samples/tree/master/BluetoothLeGatt

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following resources that should help you get started:-

- [Ultimate Guide to Android BLE Development](https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/?utm_source=BlogEmail&utm_medium=Email&utm_campaign=BlogRoundUp&mc_cid=9113555d36&mc_eid=767bbcdc1b)
- [Building Android Apps to Control Bluetooth LE Devices](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zeN88yh7YdY&feature=youtu.be)
- [Android Lollipop: BLE Matures (video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qx55Sa8UZAQ&feature=youtu.be)
- [Bluetooth LE Send String Data Between Two Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65636725/bluetooth-le-send-string-data-between-android-devices-via-application)
- [How to Use Android BLE to Communicate with Bluetooth Devices](https://medium.com/@shahar_avigezer/bluetooth-low-energy-on-android-22bc7310387a)